# Missing required xml elements error in CalDav invite-response request

Tags: python, xml, caldav

I'm trying to script an automated acceptance to shared calendar invites using python.

As per the RFC here:
https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/blob/master/doc/Extensions/caldav-sharing.txt

I've created the following xml which I send as a POST request to my calendar server:

```
accept_invite_xml = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<CS:invite-reply xmlns='DAV:' xmlns:CS='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'>
    <href>urn:x-uid:9DCA674E-5AD8-1992-7828-033C09954A5F</href>
    <CS:invite-accepted/>
    <CS:hosturl>/calendars/__uids__/419A2758-B533-3019-BF05-32CEFB6E79DC/calendar</CS:hosturl>
    <CS:in-reply-to>1e9a9754-f896-43cf-a848-d2f71f5eb10b</CS:in-reply-to>
    <CS:summary>calendar</CS:summary>
</CS:invite-reply>
"""
```

This is POST'd through the python requests package:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'charset':"utf-8"}
requests.post(url = my_calendar_home_url, 
                       auth = (username,password), 
                       data=accept_invite_xml, 
                       headers=headers)
```

But keep receiving the following response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<error xmlns='DAV:'>
  <valid-request xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'/>
  <error-description xmlns='http://twistedmatrix.com/xml_namespace/dav/'>Missing required XML elements</error-description>
</error>
```

As far as I can tell, there's no element missing in the invite-reply, and invite-reply is supposed to be the root element.  I can't access the server to check logs and debug on that side, only on the client.  Thanks.

Comment: Try  `<CS:invite-reply` without `namespace` as `<invite-reply` and `<href` as `DAV:href=...`

Comment: I know 5.4.1 says something else, but I would assume that you need to send the reply to the `notification-URL`.
You could also check what Calendar.app does in Charles (how its response differs and what URL it sends too).